# how to achieve colour B = Colour A with 30% black (#000000) transparency applied

Tags: css

Suppose I have a `box1` with `background-color :red` .
In `box2` there I need to set the `border-top` based on the background color of `box1` red (75%) and black(25%).  Whenever I changed the background color in `box1`, I need to set the border-top of `box2` (current background color of box1 (75%) and 25% black color.

Comment: Any help  to do this css function changes

Comment: You need javascript to maintain 2 boxes style. CSS alone cannot achieve your need

Comment: Thanks brickowski. Do u have any reference javascript code to achieve this one.Its really helpful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hsl()` colors where you can adjust the lightness to obtain what you want:

```css
.box {
  --color:0, 100%;
  
  border:20px solid hsl(var(--color),20%); /*50% - 30%*/
  background:hsl(var(--color),50%);  /*this is red*/

width:100px;
  height:100px;  
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--color:240, 100%;"></div>

<div class="box" style="--color:120, 100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS variables. Browser support is limited.

```
 :root{
    --box-1-color: rgb(100%,0%,0%); /*Red color*/
     }

.box-1{
        width:200px;
        background-color: var(--box-1-color);

      }
.box-2{ width:70%;
        margin: 5px auto;
        background-color:yellow;
        border-top: 3px dashed var(--box-1-color); /*Used dashed border to 
                                                   distinguish box-2's 
                                                   top-border from box 1's 
                                                   background. If you change 
                                                   color in :root, both box-1's 
                                                   background and box-2's border-top 
                                                   will change*/

      }
```

Comment: Thanks Robin .Is it possible to add -box-2 border-top (red with black color).like that background-color: rgb(113, 11, 12); I need to overlay of red with black

Comment: This is a hack. You could try inserting another element above box 2 and give it a box-shadow of black color and .25 opacity (for 25%). Then position the element in such a way that the shadow overlays box-2's top border. Otherwise, it's possible to mix colors using SASS/LESS.

Answer (score 0):

The demo make use of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). I'm not involve in the mentioned project.

> based on the background color of box1 red (75%) and black(25%)

Take RGB color model for example. Black is the result of red, green and blue value in 0 (white is red, green, blue in 255). For red, it is (255,0,0) or #FF0000. If you take 25% out from red, it is already darken. You cannot 'add' 25% black since black is (0,0,0);

Below demo has a `box2` which background color is black with 30% opacity covering part of the `box1`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="BIG5">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#color-select').on('change', function(e) {
   var selectedColor = $(e.target).val();
   $('#box1').css('background-color', selectedColor);

  })

 });
</script>
<style>
#box1 {
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 background-color: red;
}

#box2 {
 width: 48px;
 height: 12px;
 position: relative;
 top: -12px;
 left: 8px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
 <div id="box2" class="box"></div>

 <select id="color-select">
  <option selected value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
 </select>
</body>
</html>
```

As [Robin Baby's answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56470130/5594167), I believe CSS variables would be the future.

Comment: yes Brickowski, but how we add original colour +overlay of another colour like black (20%) using variable

Comment: What do you mean by overlay? Are you taking about the new color of 2 different colors mixing together? @lakshman

Comment: I need to configure like this way Pls look this image url https://imgur.com/a/yjtEi1i
The smaller part of this banner that is a darker colour (refer to this as box2 , see attached), is then to automatically change based on the chosen box1.
box2 = box1 with 30% black (#000000) transparency applied
Example :
   1. box1: background-color: red; 
   2. box 2 :border-color: #bd1414 transparent transparent. 

   Now what I need is If I will give the background colour for this box1 is green .then for the box2 border-color-top should be green (primary colour from box1)+20 or 30% black colour .

Comment: The image is a little bit blur to me. Updated the demo. See if I catch your meaning. box2 is off on purpose, to demonstrate the overlapping effect.